# Why can I only suspend using Ctrl-Z in screen under Cygwin?

Tags: windows-7, bash, cygwin, suspend, conemu

I'm using Cygwin with [ConEmu](https://github.com/Maximus5/ConEmu) in Windows 7. I can't suspend programs in bash using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> unless I'm using GNU/Screen.

I've seen suggestions to use [mintty](http://mintty.github.io/), and that works, but I'm not sure why it makes a difference. Is there a way to get <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> to work while using ConEmu?

Comment: What do you want to do with Ctrl+Z?

Comment: I want to suspend Unix programs running in Cygwin (I know it won't work with Windows programs).

Answer (score 2):

I have a similar setup -- Cygwin bash + screen in ConEmu. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd> works in both bash and in screen itself.  Perhaps you need to upgrade to the latest Cygwin version or maybe you have already gotten past this problem.

I did notice what you were talking about, though, specifically when testing with `/bin/sleep.exe`. I can't suspend that with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd> in bash, but I can inside of screen. Further, I can suspend it in bash by using `kill -17 [pid of running sleep.exe]` from another screen window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd> sends a `SIGSTOP`, which `kill -l` shows as #17).  So, ya got me... something about Cygwin's sleep.exe is funky.

Sorry to reply to an old thread on here, but I was searching for answers on a similar topic -- that of suspended processes in ConEmu in general.  I'll post in another thread on that subject.

Answer (score 1):

ConEmu does not process Ctrl+Z keycombo at all. It is your console application (shell) responsibility.

But you may "pause" console output switching Conemu to alternative buffer, Win+A keycombo by default.

Comment: That’s not surprising, since ConEmu is a Windows console emulator, and (Ctrl+Z) –– and process suspension, for that matter –– are alien to Windows.

Comment: @Scott don't know how exactly "suspension" works in *nix platforms, but ConEmu can pause console output.

Comment: Pausing the output with Win+A doesn't seem to let me issue new commands, which is part of what I want to do. I want Unix-style job control (which already works partially - Ctrl-C works as expected).

Comment: Here's where I'm confused: with bash running on Linux, Ctrl-Z works fine. On Windows (using Cygwin), it seems to vary based on console - it works in mintty, but not in ConEmu (or a few others I've tried, like Console2). But (and here's the really confusing part) if I run screen within bash, it seems to work regardless of which console I'm using. So if it always works in screen, why doesn't it always work in bash?

Comment: Why? Obviously, screen supports Ctrl+Z, bash do not supports Ctrl+Z. You may fill new issue on ConEmu project website with feature request (thorough description is required).

Comment: Except Ctrl-Z works with bash under mintty.

Comment: Still don't know exactly what Ctrl+Z doing, but suppose that mintty process this hotkey internally.

Comment: Cygwin emulates a Unix-style command line for Windows (specifically, the Bash shell). There are various shortcuts that can be used to control running processes. Ctrl-C kills the current process, Ctrl-Z allows you to pause a running process so that you can enter new commands, etc. With Cygwin, some of these shortcuts work no matter which console I'm using (like Ctrl-C), but others only work while using certain consoles. Ctrl-Z works while running Cygwin in mintty, but not in ConEmu or Console2. However, if I use the "screen" program within Cygwin, Ctrl-Z works no matter which console I use.